# Using a combination of InnoDB and MyIsam tables

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables in which I want more robustness and fortunately don't require frequent rapid fulls of data and examination.
All other tables would inevitably be MyISAM.

Can I safely use both (I've read a handful of discouragements from this) without fearing bugs or data getting affected by differences between engines?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can.

Note that only `InnoDB` tables support transactions and `FOREIGN KEY` relationships.

Answer (score 25):

You CAN but this introduces a number of disadvantages:

- Your server tuning will now necessarily be a compromise - you cannot use all the memory for either MyISAM OR InnoDB (NB: This does not apply if they are on different servers)
- Replication fails in a number of edge-cases, because if you have a failed transaction which contained changes to some MyISAM tables, it can neither correctly commit it nor roll it back
- You still can't back up your server using MVCC, because you'd still not get a consistent snapshot of MyISAM tables

So basically, I'd encourage you to switch wholly to InnoDB. Then you can pretty much forget about MyISAM and not devote resources to it, and get the full benefits of using InnoDB. Anyone who thinks MyISAM is faster is either not tuning InnoDB correctly, or has such small data that who cares.

MyISAM does faster table scans, but if you're doing those on large tables, you have bigger problems.

Comment: Nice answer MarkR, I was wondering in which "edge-cases" the replication of a mixed InnoDB/MyIsam database could fail? Only using transactions affecting both InnoDB and MyIsam tables? Do you think is that safe in any other case? Thanks

Comment: If a transaction happens on the master which involves MyISAM and innodb tables, commits succesfully, is binlogged, then on the slave, the InnoDB part of it fails with a deadlock, the transaction will get retried. However, the MyISAM part of the transaction can't be rolled back, so the slave will have to repeat it (and hope nothing bad happens) - but something bad can happen, and the entire slave gets broken (replication stopped until manual intervention). There are lots of other cases, this is an example I just invented.